# Is there rotational ambiguity in PLS?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, partial-least-squares, factor-rotation

There are linearly overlapped components typically in curve resolution or factor analysis techniques [[1]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169743911001110) [[2]](https://books.google.ch/books?id=TYPNCgAAQBAJ).

Also for PCA, it is common that it is easy to change the sign of the loadings or scores as both could be multiplied by (-1).

Given that partial least squares is constrained to two data blocks (X and Y), is it the case that there is no rotational ambiguity?

\begin{align}
X &= TP^T + E\\
Y &= TQ^T + F
\end{align}

I.e., the loadings P and Q have no ambiguity in their signs?

Comment: By definition PCA is deterministic (there is no error term) and provides a mathematically unique linear solution. Once one rotates any PCA matrix the result is no longer unique. PLS is no different in that its solutions are neither unique nor nonambiguous.

Comment: @DJohnson I wonder why is it that the positive and negative values of the loadings (and loading weights) are often used to try to understand how the variables used by the PLS model (typically solved by NIPALS)? Is that wrong?

Comment: PCA factor loadings are a metric expressing the linear association between the variable and the underlying dimension, component or factor. You really need to read up on the factor analytic literature. Lots of resources out there. SAS documentation is readily available online (e.g., Proc Factor) and there are many introductory texts. Being old school I still think Dillon and Goldstein's mid-80s text *Multivariate Statistics* remains one of the best most intuitive intros to classic multivariate stats not to mention that they are particularly fine at explaining the basic variants of PCA